# Synonym of shocking/risqué

Tags: single-word-requests

What's an adjective that can mean risqué/shocking and idiomatically used to describe revolutions in art?

> X's music video is ____

Has nudity, touches on lots of hot topics, exposes lots of taboos. Makes the artist vulnerable.

Answer (score 2):

*Edgy* includes several of the concepts in other answers, and is refers to artistic works. See definition 3.

edg·y  (ĕjē)
adj. edg·i·er, edg·i·est

1. Nervous or irritable: The performers were edgy as they waited for the show to begin.
2. Having a sharp or biting edge: an edgy wit.
3. Daring, provocative, or trend-setting: an exhibition of edgy photographs; an edgy menu.

edgi·ly adv.

edgi·ness n.

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=edgy

Answer (score 1):

[outrageous](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/outrageous)

> shocking and morally unacceptable.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Salacious (adj.)

1660s, from Latin salax (genitive salacis) "lustful," probably originally "fond of leaping," as in a male animal leaping on a female in sexual advances, from salire "to leap" (see salient (adj.)). Earliest form of the word in English is salacity (c. 1600). Related: Salaciously; salaciousness.

https://www.etymonline.com/word/salacious

Answer (score 1):

In art, that would be called ***provocative***. It bears the shocking connotation of wanting to shatter classical world views and also the taboos.
[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/provocative) gives it two meanings:

> 1. If you describe something as provocative, you mean that it is ***intended to make people react angrily or argue against it***.
> 2. If you describe someone's clothing or behaviour as provocative, you mean that it is ***intended to make someone feel sexual desire***.

About this term, [artsy.com](https://www.artsy.net/gene/provocative) says that it is

> used to describe artworks that *arouse strong feelings, whether because
> of their subject matter or technique*. In perpetually *challenging
> artistic traditions*, artists have confronted issues of ***sexuality,
> race, politics, and religion***, and ***incorporated surprising materials***
> such as dirt or bodily fluid into their works, ***often facing a backlash
> of rejection and fierce criticism from the public***.

So to be provocative does make the artist vulnerable because of the negative reactions their work provokes.

Speaking about provocative art in an article called *10 Works of Art That Made People Really Mad*, [History.com](https://www.history.com/news/most-controversial-art-in-history) comments:

> These ***controversial*** artworks shocked the world.

Another term could be ***controversial***, although I find it much milder than ***provocative***.

The article continues, and I will emphasise some words that are related to the word you are looking for:

> Artists throughout history have never shied away from ***controversy***—in fact, many even try to court ***infamy***. (Need proof? Just look at [Banksy](https://www.biography.com/artist/banksy), the anonymous street artist who recently created a work that self-destructed the moment it was sold at auction—for a whopping $1.37 million.) While it’s up to critics and historians to debate technique and artistic merit, there are some works of art that shocked most people who saw them. From paintings deemed too ***lewd***, too ***rude*** or too ***gory*** for their time to acts of so-called ***desecration*** and powerful political statements, these are some of the most controversial artworks ever created.

Another word used in this article which has these strong connotations is ***iconoclastic***. [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/iconoclastic) defines it as

> strongly opposing generally accepted beliefs and traditions:
>
> - His plays were fairly ***iconoclastic*** in their day.

In the quoted article, the word *iconoclastic* is used to describe an artist:

> When ***iconoclastic*** Marcel Duchamp anonymously submitted a porcelain urinal signed “R. Mutt 1917” as a “readymade” sculpture to the Society of Independent Artists, a group known to accept any artist who could come up with the fee‚ the unthinkable happened: the piece was denied, even though Duchamp himself was a cofounder and board member of the group.

Answer (score 0):

One word that combines the *revolutionary sense* (in the sense you mean) with *risqué* is **racy**.

> Risqué, Suggestive: *racy jokes*.

> having the distinctive quality of something in its original or most characteristic form.

[Merriam-Webster]